# Mulesoft ESB Environment Variable per Project

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm starting two Mule projects from studio. How can I set different environment variables for each project inside this one app?

If I have an application run configuration called `RunBothProjects` and that launches two projects: `hellomule` and `hellomule8082`.

For `hellomule` I want to add either an argument or environment variable that says `MULE_APP=AppOne` and for `hellomule8082` I want to add `MULE_APP=AppTwo`.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have separate environment variables because both Mule applications are deployed to the same Mule server. Environment variables are global per server.